# Does perl IO::Socket::SSL support SSLKEYLOGFILE?

Tags: perl, ssl

How can i record in perl IO::Socket:SSL the used SSL keys for decryption in wireshark? 
E.g. with curl or chrome i can use environment variable $SSLKEYLOGFILE for this.

Answer (score 4):

In short: there is currently no support for this.

IO::Socket::SSL uses Net::SSLeay for the SSL support which itself is using OpenSSL as the library implementing TLS. There is no direct support for SSLKEYLOGFILE in OpenSSL. There is a function [SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback.html) starting with OpenSSL 1.1.1 which can be used to implement the necessary functionality. But this function is not accessible from Net::SSLeay and thus not from IO::Socket::SSL or any other perl-only code.

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks for clarification! Actually, i am looking for a tool, that offers option to control the SSL/TLS handshake in more detail. I was not able to do it with curl or the openssl command line interface. E.g. i wanted to enable/disable use of Client Hello Extension "heartbeat". I hoped i could do it on openssl API level - e.g. with perl.

Comment: @FrankBergemann: Enabling heartbeat is a completely different question. It should be possible with the help of Net::SSLeay::CTX_ctrl but only if OpenSSL supports this extension (support removed with OpenSSL 1.1.0). Still, new questions should not be asked in a comment - this is a strict Q+A site and not a discussion forum.

Comment: \@Steffen: thanks again for your help. Topic solved.